# Работа с файлом в C++

Tags: c++

Мне нужно создать файл txt, после чего написать программу, которая читает по строкам файла, подсчитывает кол-во повествовательных предложений и находит в файле 3 повествовательное предложение. Программа должна быть написана без векторов.За повествовательное мы берём предложение, которое кончается точкой. Учитывать троеточие не нужно. Найти в файле 3 предложение, это значит выделить его звёздочкой с двух сторон или slash'ами.

Например:

> 1 предложение.
>   2 предложение.
>   3 предложение?
>   /\4 предложение./\

Comment: И в чем проблема? В создании файла? В открытии?

Comment: Проблема читать по строкам, после чего подсчитывать кол-во повествовательных и нахождения 3-го повествовательного.

Comment: Почему бы не уточнить вопрос и не удалить из него лишние проблемы, которых нет. К тому же, ваш "вопрос" - на самом деле два вопроса

Comment: Прощу прощения за двойной вопрос, но я немного отчаялся) Сократил немного вопрос, убрав лишнюю информацию, не относящуюся к заданию.

Comment: На будущее учту, буду создавать более содержательно название. С построчным чтением попробую разобраться.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Думаю, мое решение может помочь:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string currentSentence = "";
    char ch;
    int sentenceCounter = 0;
    ifstream infile("test.txt"); // your file
    while(infile)
    {
        infile.get(ch);
        /*
        Если текущий символ - точка, то наше предложение утвердительное
        Если счетчик меньше 2, значит увеличиваем счетчик и идем дальше
        */
        if((ch == '.') &&(sentenceCounter < 2))
        {
            sentenceCounter++;
            continue;
        }
        /*
            Если мы уже встретили две точки в файле, то сейчас будет третье предложение.
            Нужно учесть, что могут попадаться ! или ?.
            Если они попадаются, то обнуляем строку и считываем файл дальше пока не дойдем до конца или до точки.
        */
        if(sentenceCounter == 2)
        {
            if((ch != '!') && (ch != '?') && (ch != '.'))
            {
                currentSentence+=ch;
                continue;
            }
            if(ch == '.')
            {
                cout<<currentSentence;
                break;
            }
            //очищаем, если встретился восклицательный или вопросительный знак
            if((ch == '!') || (ch == '?'))
            {
                currentSentence.erase();
                continue;
            }

        }

        currentSentence += ch;
    }



    return 0;
}
```

Правда здесь предложение не выделяется звездочками, оно выводится в консоль для простоты примера. Думаю, переписать для выделения предложения звездочками не будет трудно.

Тестировал на примере `test1 . test2 ? test3 ! test4. test5? test6. test7?`, корректно выводит `test6`.

Для таких знаков препинания как точка, восклицательный и вопросительный знак, все работает. Вам следует дописать программу для распознавания многоточия. И не забывайте про поддержку русских символов.